# Grails findAll with like values

Tags: grails, findall

Trying to simply run a query of domain objects using find all and it's not acting as I would expect:

```
searchResults = Contact.findAll("from Contact as c where c.company=${params.company.id} and c.firstName = '%${nameSearch}%'  or c.lastName = '%${nameSearch}%' ")
```

I want to find all people within a company that have a first name or last name similar to the search that was entered (params.search was stored into nameSearch variable). If I change the value for first or last to a particular name "Tim" or "Johnson", it works.

What am I doing incorrectly with the variable or "like" reference? I thought the % symbol was basically the * symbol in search criteria?

I've tried the 2.0.0 form of search:

```
        searchResults = Contact.findAll{
            company == params.company.id
            firstName == '%' + nameSearch + '%'
            lastName == '%' + nameSearch + '%'
        }
```

But that didn't work either. Thank you for all help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
def company = Company.get(params.company.id)
def searchResults = Contact.withCriteria {
    eq('company', company)
    or {
        ilike('firstName', '%' + nameSearch + '%')
        ilike('lastName', '%' + nameSearch + '%')
    }
}
```

If you don't want to retrieve the `Company` instance, you could use [`idEq()`](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) within a `company { }` block instead.

---

A few things (of perhaps more) that were wrong with your HQL attempt:

- Your `company` condition was comparing an object (`c.company`) to an id value (`params.company.id`)
- You needed to group your boolean logic correctly, i.e. `(company AND (first OR last))`, instead of `(company AND first OR last)`
- You should have been using `like` instead of `=`, e.g. `firstName like '%something%'`

[As a matter of security](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20injection), **you really, really shouldn't be building your HQL statement with the values inline**. You should use named parameters instead. Check out some of the middle examples in the [`findAll` documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html).

Comment: Thanks Rob - This is exactly what I am using. Quick run through proves to be exactly what I need, but I fear my high number of domain entries. However, one thing I did notice and cannot figure out for the life of me is how to handle just two ilike scenario? I created the criteria with an ilike(lastname) or ilike(firstName) and no luck. Works fine with just one comparison.

Comment: Nevermind - I'm good. I used basic findBy's with less complex queries. Thank you again Rob for introducing me to this query code!